# Как узнать количество различных значений в столбце?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Какими запросами можно получить уникальные значения в стоблце и посчитать их количество?

Comment: @mike, а Вы сейчас не перепутали столбец с ячейкой? В столбце как раз и должно быть множество значений

Comment: @lDrakonl До вашего исправления текста вопроса, просматривался именно такой смысл. По крайней мере я так его понимал. После вашего исправления, конечно такое уже не просматривается, но вы подогнали текст вопроса под тот смысл как вы его поняли, чего делать конечно не следовало. Лучше дождаться реакции задавшего вопрос. И если он подтвердит, что ваше толкование верно, от закрыть вопрос как дубль, так как таких вопросов с ответами уже масса.

Comment: @mike на мой взгляд вопрос трактовался однозначно. Если я ошибся, ТС откатит мое изменение :)

Comment: Отчего мне кажется, что в изначальной версии вопроса спрашивалось про получение списка всех встречаемых значений с указанием числа совпадающих строк для каждого из значений?

Comment: @Мелкий Вот, у вас уже 3я версия толкования изначального вопроса :) я думал вообще, что надо посчитать слова в строке. Ждем автора вопроса ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество различных значений:

```
select count(dictinct <column_name>) 
from   <table>
```

Сами различные значения:

```
select dictinct <column_name>
from   <table>
```